# Not Able To Connect Storj Node with Quic connection

Tags: go, distributed-computing, quic

I am deploying storj service setup in my local and with that I am trying to connect new node with that service.

I am having 2 machines machine1 and machine2
machine1 contains entire storj setup
machine2 contains the new node.

from machine2 when I deploy node directly with some storj command it is working fine. but when I am deploying that inside docker it is not working. it gives quic error

"contact: failed to ping storage node using QUIC, your node indicated error code: 0, rpc: quic: timeout: no recent network activity"

I have tried multiple different setting shared online. but nothing is working for all I am getting same error.